# T-SQL: can I use a variable as a database reference

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I want to accomplish this:

```
update @sourceDatabase.dbo.PredictedPrices
```

and then set `@sourceDatabase` as a variable.

But I'm not allowed?

```
Incorrect syntax near '.'.
```

Is there another way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this to be done you need to use [`SP_ExecuteSQL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) . i.e dynamic query execution

**Example:**

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql 
          N'SELECT * FROM AdventureWorks2008R2.HumanResources.Employee 
          WHERE BusinessEntityID = @level',
          N'@level tinyint',
          @level = 109;
```

Comment: didn't work for this: EXECUTE sp_executesql  N'update @sourceDatabase.dbo.PredictedPrices set MinPrice = MinPrice'

Comment: @Michel - You need to concatenate into the string. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 8):

```
DECLARE @Dynsql NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sourceDatabase sysname
DECLARE @MinPrice MONEY

SET @sourceDatabase = 'foo'
SET @MinPrice = 1.00

SET @Dynsql =  N'update ' + QUOTENAME(@sourceDatabase) + '.dbo.PredictedPrices 
       set MinPrice = @MinPrice'


EXECUTE sp_executesql   @Dynsql,
                      N'@MinPrice money',
                        @MinPrice = @MinPrice;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're running this script in SSMS, you can use [SQLCMD Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174187.aspx) (found under the Query menu) to script a variable for your database name:

```
:setvar sourceDatabase YourDatabaseName

update $(sourceDatabase).dbo.PredictedPrices
    set ...
```